Migrate Gradle Groovy to Kotlin DSL Modularization
I am trying to migrate my gradle project from groovy to kotlin dsl.
Hopefully theres some one can help me.
So, my project used modularization and this is how my project structure looks like
root
├── shared_build.gradle
├── shared_build_core.gradle
├── shared_build_feature.gradle
├── shared_build_sub_feature.gradle
├── build.gradle
│  
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│  
├── core
│   │
│   ├── core-data
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │
│   ├── core-navigation
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │
│   ├── core-resource
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │
│   ├── core-analytics
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │
│   └── core-util
│       ├── build.gradle
│  
│  
├── features
│   ├── feature-auth
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │
│   ├── feature-home
│   │   ├── build.gradle
│   └── ...
│   
└── settings.gradle

yap its complicated. this is code legacy from my senior (he got resign).
i tried to breakdown one by one.
there is 3 type of module :

core module
feature module
sub-feature module

for achieve the clean code on gradle every core, feature, and sub-feature he make a share gradle which :

share_build.gradle : top level share gradle
share_build_core.gradle : for core module (apply from share_build.gradle)
share_build_feature.gradle : for feature module (apply from share_build.gradle)
share_build_sub_feature.gradle : for sub feature module (apply from share_build.gradle)

here is step i did for migrate
before using version contorl i used the versions.gradle file like this.
ext.versions = [
        //region Release

        code                       : 68,
        name                       : "2.15.0",

        //release version 60
        schemaDatabaseVersion      : 62,
        schemaDatabaseBeforeVersion: 61,


        //endregion
        //region SDK

        compileSdkVersion          : 33,
        minSdkVersion              : 27,
        targetSdkVersion           : 33,

        //endregion
        //region Plugin

        agp                        : '8.5.0',
        crashlytics                : '2.5.2',
        google_services            : '4.3.14',
        kotlin                     : '1.8.0',
        navigation_safe_args       : '2.5.0',
        firebase_perf_plugin       : '1.4.1',
]

ext.plugin = [
        agp                 : "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$versions.agp",
        crashlytics         : "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:$versions.crashlytics",
        google_services     : "com.google.gms:google-services:$versions.google_services",
        kotlin              : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$versions.kotlin",
        navigation_safe_args: "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$versions.navigation_safe_args",
        firebase_perf       : "com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:$versions.firebase_perf_plugin",
        oneSignal           : "gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:$versions.oneSignal"
]

ext.deps = [
        //region Common

        stdlib              : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$versions.kotlin",
        coroutines          : [
                "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$versions.coroutine",
                "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$versions.coroutine"
        ],
        material            : "com.google.android.material:material:$versions.material",
        koin                : [
                "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$versions.koin",
                "io.insert-koin:koin-android-compat:$versions.koin",
                "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-workmanager:$versions.koin",
                "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-navigation:$versions.koin"
        ],
        jdk_lib             : "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:$versions.jdk_lib",
        kotlin_reflect      : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$versions.kotlin_reflect",
]

i create a version control (libs.versions.toml)
libs.versions.toml
its just a few dependencies i used.
[versions]

#plugins
agp = "8.5.0"
kotlin = "1.8.0"

#dependencies
dexguard = "9.8.0"
kotlinGradle = "1.8.0"
navigationSafeArgs = "2.5.3"
googleServices = "4.3.15"
firebasePlugin = "2.9.5"
firebasePerfPlugin = "1.4.1"

#Koin
koin = "3.2.2"

# JetPack
lifecycle = "2.6.0-alpha04"
appCompat = "1.7.0-alpha01"
core = "1.10.0-alpha01"

# Firebase
firebaseBom = "31.4.0"
firebaseConfig = "21.1.2"

# Extras
debugBanner = "1.0.4"
leakCanary = "2.10"
logger = "2.2.0"
localeHelper = "1.1.4"
dateTimeUtils = "v0.2.1"
lottie = "5.2.0"

# Encryption and Security
sqlcipher = "4.5.3"

# Material
material = "1.8.0-rc01"

#Common Dependencies
stdLib = "1.3.41"
kotlinReflect = "1.4.0"
jdkLib = "1.0.9"

#Testing
junit = "4.13-beta-3"
truth = "1.0-rc2"
robolectric = "4.9.2"
hamcrest = "2.1"
test_core = "1.4.0-alpha05"
test_runner = "1.4.0-alpha05"
test_rules = "1.4.0-alpha05"
test_espresso = "3.3.0-alpha01"
test_ext_junit_ktx = "1.1.3-alpha05"
test_ext_truth = "1.3.0-alpha01"
test_fragment = "1.2.0-alpha01"
mockk = "1.13.3"
test_livedata = "2.1.0"

#Security
securityCrypto = "1.1.0-alpha02"
securePreferences = "0.1.7"

#Gson
gson = "2.10.1"

[libraries]

#common dependencies
kotlinStdLib = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-stdlib", version.ref = "stdLib" }
kotlinReflect = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-reflect", version.ref = "kotlinReflect" }
jdkLib = { group = "com.android.tools", name = "desugar_jdk_libs", version.ref = "jdkLib" }


#dependencies
gradlePlugin = { group = "com.android.tools.build", name = "gradle", version.ref = "agp" }
dexguard = { group = "com.guardsquare", name = "dexguard-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "dexguard" }
kotlinGradle = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "kotlinGradle" }
navigationSafeArgs = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "navigationSafeArgs" }
googleServices = { group = "com.google.gms", name = "google-services", version.ref = "googleServices" }
firebasePlugin = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-crashlytics-gradle", version.ref = "firebasePlugin" }
firebasePrerfPlugin = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "perf-plugin", version.ref = "firebasePerfPlugin" }


# koin
koin-android = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-android", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-android-compat = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-android-compat", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-androidx-workmanager = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-androidx-workmanager", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-androidx-navigation = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-androidx-navigation", version.ref = "koin" }

# JetPack
lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycle" }
lifecycle-livedata-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-livedata-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycle" }
lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate", version.ref = "lifecycle" }
lifecycle-common-java8 = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-common-java8", version.ref = "lifecycle" }
lifecycle-service = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-service", version.ref = "lifecycle" }
lifecycle-process = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-process", version.ref = "lifecycle" }

appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appCompat" }
appcompat-resources = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat-resources", version.ref = "appCompat" }

core = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version = "core" }

# Firebase
firebase-bom = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebaseBom" }
firebase-analytics-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-analytics-ktx" }
firebase-crashlytics-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-crashlytics-ktx" }
firebase-perf = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-perf" }
firebase-config-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-config-ktx", version.ref = "firebaseConfig" }
firebase-messaging-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-messaging-ktx" }

# Extras
debugBanner = { group = "com.github.armcha", name = "DebugBanner", version.ref = "debugBanner" }
leakCanary = { group = "com.squareup.leakcanary", name = "leakcanary-android", version.ref = "leakCanary" }
logger = { group = "com.orhanobut", name = "logger", version.ref = "logger" }
localeHelper = { group = "com.zeugmasolutions.localehelper", name = "locale-helper-android", version.ref = "localeHelper" }
dateTimeUtils = { group = "com.github.fadhyyusuf", name = "BithealthDateTimeUtils", version.ref = "dateTimeUtils" }
lottie = { group = "com.airbnb.android", name = "lottie", version.ref = "lottie" }


# Encryption and Security
sqlcipher = { group = "net.zetetic", name = "android-database-sqlcipher", version.ref = "sqlcipher" }

# Material
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }

#Testing
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
truth = { group = "com.google.truth", name = "truth", version.ref = "truth" }
robolectric = { group = "org.robolectric", name = "robolectric", version.ref = "robolectric" }
hamcrest = { group = "org.hamcrest", name = "hamcrest", version.ref = "hamcrest" }
test_core = { group = "androidx.test", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "test_core" }
test_runner = { group = "androidx.test", name = "runner", version.ref = "test_runner" }
test_rules = { group = "androidx.test", name = "rules", version.ref = "test_rules" }
test_espresso_contrib = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-contrib", version.ref = "test_espresso" }
test_espresso_intents = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-intents", version.ref = "test_espresso" }
test_espresso_accessibility = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-accessibility", version.ref = "test_espresso" }
test_espresso_remote = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-remote", version.ref = "test_espresso" }
test_espresso_idling_concurrent = { group = "androidx.test.espresso.idling", name = "idling-concurrent", version.ref = "test_espresso" }
test_espresso_idling_net = { group = "androidx.test.espresso.idling", name = "idling-net", version.ref = "test_espresso" }
test_ext_junit_ktx = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit-ktx", version.ref = "test_ext_junit_ktx" }
test_ext_truth = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "truth", version.ref = "test_ext_truth" }
test_fragment = { group = "androidx.fragment", name = "fragment-testing", version.ref = "test_fragment" }
mockk = { group = "io.mockk", name = "mockk", version.ref = "mockk" }
test_livedata = { group = "androidx.arch.core", name = "core-testing", version.ref = "test_livedata" }

#Security
securityCrypto = { group = "androidx.security", name = "security-crypto", version.ref = "securityCrypto" }
securePreferences = { group = "com.scottyab", name = "secure-preferences-lib", version.ref = "securePreferences" }

#Gson
gson = { group = "com.google.code.gson", name = "gson", version.ref = "gson" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
googleGms = { id = "com.google.gms.google-services", version.ref = "googleServices" }
firebaseCrashlytics = { id = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics", version.ref = "firebasePlugin" }
firebasePerf = { id = "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf", version.ref = "firebasePerfPlugin" }

benManesVersions = { id = "com.github.ben-manes.versions", version = "0.42.0" }
detekt = { id = "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt", version = "1.23.3" }
sonarqube = { id = "org.sonarqube", version = "4.2.1.3168" }
kotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version = "1.8.0" }

next is i success to migrate my build.gradle level project and app
heres the gradle :
build.gradle level project
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.dexguard)
        classpath(libs.kotlinGradle)
        classpath(libs.gradlePlugin)
        classpath(libs.navigationSafeArgs)
        classpath(libs.googleServices)
        classpath(libs.firebasePlugin)
        classpath(libs.firebasePrerfPlugin)
    }
}


plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.benManesVersions)
    alias(libs.plugins.detekt)
    alias(libs.plugins.sonarqube)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid) apply false
}


subprojects {
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            allWarningsAsErrors = false
        }
    }
}

sonar {
    properties {
        property("sonar.projectKey", "xxxxxxxxxx")
        property("sonar.projectName", "xxxxxxxxx")
    }
}

detekt {
    allRules = false
    config.setFrom("$projectDir/detekt.yml")
    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
        txt.required.set(true)
    }
}

tasks.withType<io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt> {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

and this is build.gradle level app
build.gradle level app
import java.util.Properties
import java.io.FileInputStream

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf")
    id("dexguard")
}


apply(from = "../shared_build.gradle")

val keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keys/keystore.properties")
val keystoreProperties = Properties().apply {
    load(FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.xxx"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments(
                    mapOf(
                        "room.schemaLocation" to "$projectDir/schemas",
                        "room.incremental" to "true",
                        "room.expandProjection" to "true"
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties["releaseKeyAlias"] as String
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties["releaseKeyPassword"] as String
            storeFile = file(keystoreProperties["releaseStoreFile"] as String)
            storePassword = keystoreProperties["releaseStorePassword"] as String
        }
        create("preProd") {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties["preprodKeyAlias"] as String
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties["preprodKeyPassword"] as String
            storeFile = file(keystoreProperties["preprodStoreFile"] as String)
            storePassword = keystoreProperties["preprodStorePassword"] as String
        }
        create("stagingProd") {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties["stagingProdKeyAlias"] as String
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties["stagingProdKeyPassword"] as String
            storeFile = file(keystoreProperties["stagingProdStoreFile"] as String)
            storePassword = keystoreProperties["stagingProdStorePassword"] as String
        }
        create("staging") {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties["stagingKeyAlias"] as String
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties["stagingKeyPassword"] as String
            storeFile = file(keystoreProperties["stagingStoreFile"] as String)
            storePassword = keystoreProperties["stagingStorePassword"] as String
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties["debugKeyAlias"] as String
            keyPassword = keystoreProperties["debugKeyPassword"] as String
            storeFile = file(keystoreProperties["debugStoreFile"] as String)
            storePassword = keystoreProperties["debugStorePassword"] as String
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isCrunchPngs = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
        }
        create("preProd") {
            isCrunchPngs = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = true
            applicationIdSuffix = ".preProd"
            versionNameSuffix = "-preProd"
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("preProd")
        }
        create("stagingProd") {
            initWith(buildTypes.getByName("debug"))
            isCrunchPngs = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = true
            applicationIdSuffix = ".stagingProd"
            versionNameSuffix = "-stagingProd"
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("stagingProd")
        }
        create("staging") {
            initWith(buildTypes.getByName("debug"))
            isCrunchPngs = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = true
            applicationIdSuffix = ".staging"
            versionNameSuffix = "-staging"
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("staging")
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            ext["alwaysUpdateBuildId"] = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix = "-dev"
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
//            configure<FirebasePerformanceExtension> {
//                setInstrumentationEnabled(false)
//            }
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "META-INF/*.kotlin_module"
        }
    }

    namespace = "com.example.xxx"
//    lint {
//        isAbortOnError = false
//        isCheckReleaseBuilds = false
//        isWarningsAsErrors = false
//    }
}

dexguard {
    path = "D:\\DexGuard\\DexGuard-9.8.0\\DexGuard-9.8.0"
    license = "D:\\DexGuard\\dexguard-license.txt"
    configurations {
        register("release") {
            defaultConfiguration("dexguard-release.pro")
            configurations("dexguard-project.txt")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // region Module
    implementation(project(":feature-home"))
    implementation(project(":feature-auth"))
    implementation(project(":core-data"))
    implementation(project(":core-navigation"))
    implementation(project(":core-resource"))
    implementation(project(":core-analytics"))
    implementation(project(":core-util"))
    implementation(project(":core-integration"))
    // endregion

    // region Common
    implementation(libs.koin.android)
    implementation(libs.koin.android.compat)
    implementation(libs.koin.androidx.workmanager)
    implementation(libs.koin.androidx.navigation)
    // endregion

    // region JetPack
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.savedstate)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.common.java8)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.service)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.process)
    // endregion

    // region Firebase
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))
    implementation(libs.firebase.analytics.ktx)
    implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics.ktx)
    implementation(libs.firebase.perf)
    implementation(libs.firebase.config.ktx)
    implementation(libs.firebase.messaging.ktx)
    // endregion

    // region Extras
    implementation(libs.debugBanner)
    debugImplementation(libs.leakCanary)
    implementation(libs.logger)
    implementation(libs.localeHelper)
    // endregion

    // region encryption and security
    implementation(libs.sqlcipher)
    // endregion

    implementation(libs.material)
    // implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk")
}

and heres the issue.
i cant refactor all the shared gradle even i tried to change the module i got stuck.
ill show you the share gradle file before i refactor it.
share_build.gradle
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion versions.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion versions.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode versions.code
        versionName versions.name
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    //region Common

    implementation deps.stdlib
    implementation deps.kotlin_reflect
    coreLibraryDesugaring deps.jdk_lib

    //endregion
    //region JetPack

    implementation deps.appcompat

    //endregion
    //region Bithealth

    implementation deps.date_time_utils

    //endregion
    //region Extras

    implementation deps.logger
    implementation deps.timber
    implementation deps.lottie

    //endregion
    //region Local Testing

    testImplementation deps.test_core
    testImplementation deps.test_runner
    testImplementation deps.test_rules
    testImplementation deps.test_junit_ktx
    testImplementation deps.robolectric
    testImplementation deps.mockk
    testImplementation deps.test_livedata
    testImplementation deps.test_coroutine

    //endregion
    //region Instrumentation Testing

    androidTestImplementation deps.test_core
    androidTestImplementation deps.test_runner
    androidTestImplementation deps.test_rules
    androidTestImplementation deps.test_junit_ktx
    androidTestImplementation deps.test_livedata

    //endregion

    //region Encryption

    implementation deps.securityCrypto
    implementation deps.securePreferences

    //endregion

    //region Gson
    implementation deps.gson
    //endregion
}

share_build_core.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: '../shared_build.gradle'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_NAME", "\"${versions.name}\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_CODE", "\"${versions.code}\"")
        }
        preProd {
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_NAME", "\"${versions.name}\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_CODE", "\"${versions.code}\"")
        }
        stagingProd {
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_NAME", "\"${versions.name}\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_CODE", "\"${versions.code}\"")
        }
        staging {
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_NAME", "\"${versions.name}\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_CODE", "\"${versions.code}\"")
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_NAME", "\"${versions.name}\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "VERSION_CODE", "\"${versions.code}\"")
        }
    }
}

and some gradle from core module
apply from: '../shared_build_core.gradle'

android {
    namespace 'com.example.xxx.core.analytics'
}

dependencies {
    //region Module

    implementation project(':core-data')
    implementation project(':core-integration')

    //endregion
    //region Common

    implementation deps.koin

    //endregion
    //region JetPack

    implementation deps.core

    //endregion
    //region Firebase

    implementation platform(deps.firebase)
    implementation deps.firebase_analytics
    implementation deps.firebase_crashlytics

    //endregion
}

and here is the issue.

i cant access my toml file at share gradle and gradle core module
i get this error e: file:///D:/project/shared_build.gradle.kts:7:1: Unresolved reference: android

Sorry for the long explanation from me.
Thankyou.

Your shared_build.gradle.kts cannot call the android function because an Android Gradle plugin (which causes that function to be created) has not been applied in that file. This is not a problem in Groovy because Groovy, not being a statically typed language, does not require the functions called to be accessible at compile time.
To continue with your plan to migrate to Kotlin DSL, you need to migrate this file to a Kotlin-compliant form. There are essentially two possibilities: a plugin defined within a class (a binary plugin) or a precompiled script plugin.
Precompiled script plugins would be the most natural solution here. I wrote an answer earlier in the year explaining how to do this.
I would note the following:

The file needs to move to a separate Gradle build to become a precompiled script plugin in order that it can be compiled before it is used by your main build. The easiest way to do this is to locate it in the buildSrc project and more specifically in the buildSrc/src/main/kotlin folder.
The Android plugins you wish to apply need to be on the classpath of new plugin's compilation, and then applied in the plugins block of the precompiled script plugins as appropriate. My answer here shows how to do that for the Android Gradle plugins. (Note that you will have to decide if a given precompiled script plugin applies the Android Application Gradle plugin, the Android Library Gradle plugin, or both to suit the needs of the build files and projects that ultimately use those plugins).

